# undefined is not an object when using axios

Tags: react-native, api, axios, get, coingecko

I am using the code below to get data from the CoinGecko API and then set states to the data returned however when I console.log for example general.data, 'undefined' is being logged.  Can someone point out how the code is to be modified such that it functions as required?

```
  const [currentChartData, setChart] = useState();
  const [currentIndicator, setIndicator] = useState();
  const [bitcoinGeneral, setGeneral] = useState();
  const [yearData, setYearData] = useState();
  const [monthData, setMonthData] = useState();
  const [dayData, setDayData] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const general = await axios.get('https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/bitcoin?localization=false&tickers=false&market_data=true&community_data=false&developer_data=false&sparkline=true')
      if(general.data)
      setGeneral(general.data);

      const year = await axios.get('https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/bitcoin/market_chart?vs_currency=eur&days=365&interval=daily')
      if(year.data)
      setYearData(year.data);

      const month = await axios.get('https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/bitcoin/market_chart?vs_currency=eur&days=30&interval=daily')
      if(month.data)
      setMonthData(month.data);

      const day = await axios.get('https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/bitcoin/market_chart?vs_currency=eur&days=1&interval=hourly')
      if(day.data)
      setDayData(day.data);
    }
    fetchData()
  }, [])
```

[image]

Comment: you are setting `bitcoinGeneral` variable in `setGeneral` using `general.data`. Can you add the sample response of `general.data`?

Comment: This JSON: https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/bitcoin?localization=false&tickers=false&market_data=true&community_data=false&developer_data=false&sparkline=true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your component is rendered once before `useEffect()` is called. During that run, `bitcoinGeneral` value is `undefined`. Hence you are seeing that error.

To fix it, use [optional chaining operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) `?.` while accessing that state.

```
<Text>{bitcoinGeneral?.symbol.toUpperCase()}</Text>
```

You have to do this in all places where `bitcoinGeneral` is accessed.

Another option is to do conditional rendering. Example -

```js
if (!bitcoinGeneral) {
  return null; // or something else
}

return (
  <View>
    <Text>{bitcoinGeneral.symbol.toUpperCase()}</Text>
  </View>
)
```